# Exception "The content cannot be set on a BinaryFileResponse instance." thrown only on production server

Tags: php, laravel, csv

I want my users to download a .csv file.

The code in my controller works flawlessly on my local machine and on a dev server. However, it doesn't work on the production server.

The framework is `Laravel 5.5.44`

The PHP version is `7.2`

```php
$videos = Video::whereNotNull('title')->get();

//First row for labels
$list = array([
    'id'            => 'Video ID',
    'director'      => 'Director',
    'title'         => 'Title',
]);

foreach($videos as $video) {
    $list[] = [
        'id'            => $video->id,
        'director'      => $video->director,
        'title'         => $video->title,
    ];
}

$today = date('Ymd');
$filename = $today.'-list.csv';
$fp = fopen(storage_path($filename), 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);

return response()->download(storage_path($filename));
```

When firing the controller on the production server, I get:
`prod.ERROR: The content cannot be set on a BinaryFileResponse instance.` instead of downloading the file.

**I just noticed that the exception is thrown only if the app environment is set to production.**

I was able to reproduce the behaviour on my local machine by setting

`APP_ENV=prod` in the `.env` file.

I'm puzzled. I wasn't able to find enough information in the official documentation and I still don't know how to solve this strange issue.

Comment: can you show a little bit from that stack trace ... do you have a middleware that is altering the response object?

Comment: @lagbox here is the [log](https://pastebin.com/8DupA8Wk)

Comment: @lagbox you gave me an idea and I probably found the issue. The output in production mode is actually minified by [this plugin](https://github.com/vrkansagara/LaraOutPress)... I tried to disable it and the exception is not thrown anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AfterMiddleware` is trying to set content on the Response, which you can not do to a `BinaryFileResponse` object, any calls to `setContent` will cause this error.

You will have to figure out if you need the `vrkansagara/lara-out-press` middleware you are using.